# Lightweight web server with distributed database better than couchapp?

Tags: php, rest, mongodb, couchdb, couchapp

My company is developing a novel browser-based user interface so I need a "back end" to store some data.

Currently we're using a few PHP scripts and MySQL on a local (client) installation of [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/).

The user interface will use the browser to talk to the back end using a [REST API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) so we should be able to use any web server/db combination.

We really want to:

1. Reduce the overhead of insatlling something as large as WAMP.
2. Have the database easily distributable (peer to peer or to a central server).

The workload won't be high.

I was thinking that the backend could be implemented as a [couchapp](http://couchapp.org/page/index) because:

1. The webserver and database are packaged together.
2. [couchdb](http://couchdb.apache.org/) is supposed to be easily replicated.

I'm a bit worried about the seeming [lack of serious projects using couchdb](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/CouchDB_in_the_wild) and the announcement that [Ubuntu is dropping couchdb](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-desktop/2011-November/003474.html) (although we won't have the same scalability issues as Ubuntu).

Do you know if there are any webserver/db solutions that are easy to install on the client, easy to replicate the data and likely to be maintained for a few years?

Comment: If you think that all you need is a REST server and a NOSQL database in the back end then you should give couchdb a try.

Answer (score 1):

Your situation sounds ideally suited to a CouchApp. It's easy to distribute, and takes care of the whole HTTP API to the database for you, letting you get on with doing some cool browser UI :)

As for a "lack of serious projects", all I can say is that I consult writing CouchApps and I've used them in a number of real-world projects. There's a bit of a learning curve if you're not used to using CouchDB, but it's a great way to develop.

Myself and a number of other CouchApp developers recently released some tools for CouchApp development you might find useful: http://kan.so ...rest assured, we're taking CouchApps seriously!

Comment: Can you cite _any_ profesional-quality examples of couchapp in use? I can't find any organisation that is using couchdb seriously, let alone couchapps. I'm not trying to flamebait but I'm nervous that the community around couchapps will get bored an move onto the next fad!